# How to bypass recaptcha human check in nightwatch test?

Tags: testing, backbone.js, nightwatch.js

I'm writing a nightwatch test for a Backbone View that includes [Google's "recaptcha" human check](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html). Obviously, the test is a bot, and so it can't pass the test. So I'm trying to figure out a way to bypass the human check in the test. Can anyone suggest a way to do this that is elegant?

At the moment, the only possibility I can see is setting a query parameter on the url that nightwatch uses to load the page, and then checking for that query parameter within the logic of the Backbone view, but this seems bad. I don't want to have to include logic about testing in the code itself. It's just messy.

Thoughts?

Comment: I would not make a URL param. That's a textbook example of security by obscurity. On the other hand, isn't your own server involved in the process of verifying a captcha? In that case you could use an environment variable to indicate that you're running tests, check for that and just ignore whatever the result of the challenge is. It's still not pretty but unlike the URL param its now at least contained to your server side and the client can't override the captcha.

Comment: @ivarni nice idea. It is a bit messy, but there aren't that many other possibilities here. I'm surprised that no better solution exists as I suppose this occurs often. We're still investigating how best to do this.

Comment: Not really my idea per se, NODE_ENV is used in many node modules (e.g. [express](http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2015/07/22/the-drastic-effects-of-omitting-node_env-in-your-express-js-applications/)) to change certain behaviours depending on context. I just saw that a while ago, figured it was better than most of the alternatives to use the system environment and use it most of the time I'm faced with something like this.

Comment: Check this : https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha.-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 0):

I see Raymond's comment above has the same answer, but I still think to add an answer here should be more visible.

**Google has the document for how to bypass reCAPTCHA in test environment, check this:**
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha.-what-should-i-do

For production, I think it's not possible unless you have some smart OCR tools like endtest offers: https://endtest.io/guides/docs/dealing-with-recaptcha/