# Bypass google recaptcha for bot test

Tags: testing, bots, recaptcha

Has there anyone come out with a good way to bypass a Recaptcha check in a page to launch a bot test?

Basically, I want for a particular bot (for which I know the IP address) to bypass a google recaptcha check and not sure what would be the most apropiate way of doing it.

I have seen this question [How to bypass recaptcha human check in nightwatch test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239690/how-to-bypass-recaptcha-human-check-in-nightwatch-test)
but it does not seem to give a clear anwser.

Thanks

EDIT

I am referring myself to the invisible recaptcha that will show some random images and thus the bot will not know where to click to pass the check.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like there is a special set of test keys you can use.

If you configure your testing environment to use these keys, reCaptcha will always return a valid response.

Excerpt from the link below:

> With the following test keys, you will always get No CAPTCHA and all
>   verification requests will pass.
>
> Site key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI
>
> Secret key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe
>
> The reCAPTCHA widget will show a warning message to claim that it's
>   only for testing purpose. Please do not use these keys for your
>   production traffic.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha-v2-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have control over the server:

You can create a if check when validating the captcha on the server side. So when you make the call to google, surround it with an if() check that checks for the current IP, and if it matches a certain IP, or an array of IP's then ignore the validation.

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== 'x.x.x.x') {
 //Code that checks captcha and returns error if invalid
}
```

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear enough. The problem is when using the invisible recaptcha, meaning that the bot will see some random images and won't know where to click. How would you manage this case?

Comment: In that case, do this where you include the initiation for the invisible captcha. So it won't even get loaded.